# CSS Selector for Absence of Tag

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Given this HTML:

```
<div class="entry">
    <a class="meta">Aug. 20, 2010</a>
    <div class="content">
        <h2><a href="#">Hello.</a></h2>
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="entry">
    <a class="meta">Aug. 20, 2010</a>
    <div class="content">
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
.entry{
    width: 760px;
}

.entry .meta{
    float: left
    width: 160px;
}

.entry .content{
    float: right;
    width: 600px;
}
```

Is there a selector to add a `margin-top: 25px;` to `.entry .meta` in the absence of the `<h2>` tag? Or will I need to resort to JavaScript for this?

Comment: Nope. Javascript. However, you *could* add 25px margin to the `p` after `h2` in case the `h2` does not exist with CSS

Comment: @Yi Jiang, we dont need js for this, simple CSS can solve it, see my answer

Comment: @Starx "add a `margin-top: 25px` to `.entry .meta`" His words, not mine.

Comment: @Yi Jang... My Misunderstanding

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
.content > h2+p { margin:1px; }
.content > p { margin-top:25px; }
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mQ8AK/)

Comment: I wanted to add `margin-top: 25px` to `.meta`, as to move it down even with the content in `.content`. This moves the content down instead.

Comment: As the h2 and p don't have any parent or child relation to .meta, it is not possible through CSS, You need script to do so.